# Kivy App works well on my PC(linux) but on my phone the .apk crash before starting

Tags: python, crash, kivy

I've posted my adb logcat below:

```
04-07 09:56:38.338  4817  7429 I ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=org.test.weather/org.renpy.android.PythonActivity (has extras)} from uid 10037 on display 0
04-07 09:56:38.349  3695  4174 D audio_hw_primary: enable_snd_device: snd_device(78: vi-feedback)
04-07 09:56:38.349  3695  4174 D audio_hw_primary: enable_audio_route: usecase(21) apply and update mixer path: spkr-vi-record
04-07 09:56:38.376  3695  4174 D audio_hw_primary: enable_audio_route: usecase(1) apply and update mixer path: low-latency-playback
04-07 09:56:38.401  4817 10577 I ActivityManager: Start proc 12803:org.test.weather:python/u0a137 for activity org.test.weather/org.renpy.android.PythonActivity
04-07 09:56:38.404 12803 12803 I art     : Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
04-07 09:56:38.600 12803 12803 W ResourceType: No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
04-07 09:56:38.605 12803 12803 V python  : metadata fullscreen is1
04-07 09:56:38.641 12803 12803 I SDLSurface: Surface will NOT be transparent
04-07 09:56:38.686 12803 12820 W ResourceType: No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
04-07 09:56:38.726 12803 12820 W linker  : /data/app/org.test.weather-2/lib/arm/libpython2.7.so: is missing DT_SONAME will use basename as a replacement: "libpython2.7.so"
04-07 09:56:38.738 12803 12820 W linker  : /data/data/org.test.weather/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so: is missing DT_SONAME will use basename as a replacement: "_io.so"
04-07 09:56:38.743 12803 12820 W linker  : /data/data/org.test.weather/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/unicodedata.so: is missing DT_SONAME will use basename as a replacement: "unicodedata.so"
04-07 09:56:38.757 12803 12820 I python  : Starting audio thread
04-07 09:56:38.764 12803 12821 I Adreno  : QUALCOMM build                   : a5b4970, If5818605d9
04-07 09:56:38.764 12803 12821 I Adreno  : Build Date                       : 10/12/16
04-07 09:56:38.764 12803 12821 I Adreno  : OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.09.00.04
04-07 09:56:38.764 12803 12821 I Adreno  : Local Branch                     : N24D
04-07 09:56:38.764 12803 12821 I Adreno  : Remote Branch                    : 
04-07 09:56:38.764 12803 12821 I Adreno  : Remote Branch                    : 
04-07 09:56:38.764 12803 12821 I Adreno  : Reconstruct Branch               : 
04-07 09:56:38.796 12803 12821 I OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
04-07 09:56:38.796 12803 12821 D OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
04-07 09:56:38.800 12803 12822 I SDLSurface: Choose egl configuration
04-07 09:56:38.800 12803 12822 I SDLSurface: Try to use graphics config R8G8B8A8S8
04-07 09:56:38.806 12803 12822 W SDLSurface: Create egl surface
04-07 09:56:38.889  3695  4174 D audio_hw_primary: disable_audio_route: usecase(1) reset and update mixer path: low-latency-playback
04-07 09:56:38.903  3695  4174 D audio_hw_primary: disable_snd_device: snd_device(78: vi-feedback)
04-07 09:56:38.903  3695  4174 D audio_hw_primary: disable_audio_route: usecase(21) reset and update mixer path: spkr-vi-record
04-07 09:56:38.966 12803 12822 I python  : presplash-fit is null
04-07 09:56:38.970 12803 12822 I python  : presplash (fit=null) mx=1.054688,my=1.751953
04-07 09:56:38.985  4817  4862 I ActivityManager: Displayed org.test.weather/org.renpy.android.PythonActivity: +601ms
04-07 09:56:38.991 12803 12822 I libSDL  : Physical screen resolution is 1080x1794
04-07 09:56:38.992 12803 12822 I python  : Initialize Python for Android
04-07 09:56:38.994 12803 12803 W InputMethodManager: Ignoring onBind: cur seq=1293, given seq=1292
04-07 09:56:39.049 14637 14637 W GsaWebView: Went back to non-search URL:about:blank
04-07 09:56:39.109  7424  7424 I MemoryTrimmer: Trimming objects from memory, since app is in the background.
04-07 09:56:39.119 12803 12822 I python  : ['/data/user/0/org.test.weather/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/data/user/0/org.test.weather/files/lib/site-python']
04-07 09:56:39.119 12803 12822 I python  : Android path ['/data/user/0/org.test.weather/files/lib/python27.zip', '/data/user/0/org.test.weather/files/lib/python2.7', '/data/user/0/org.test.weather/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/data/user/0/org.test.weather/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/data/user/0/org.test.weather/files', '/data/user/0/org.test.weather/files/_applibs']
04-07 09:56:39.119 12803 12822 I python  : Android kivy bootstrap done. __name__ is __main__
04-07 09:56:39.119 12803 12822 I python  : Run user program, change dir and execute main.py
04-07 09:56:39.144 14637 11134 I PBSessionCacheImpl: Deleted sessionId[32652588711167865] from persistence.
04-07 09:56:39.286 12803 12822 I python  : [INFO              ] [Logger      ] Record log in /data/user/0/org.test.weather/files/.kivy/logs/kivy_17-04-07_9.txt
04-07 09:56:39.286 12803 12822 I python  : [INFO              ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.1
04-07 09:56:39.286 12803 12822 I python  : [INFO              ] [Python      ] v2.7.2 (default, Apr  6 2017, 18:38:40) 
04-07 09:56:39.286 12803 12822 I python  : [GCC 4.8]
04-07 09:56:39.301 12803 12822 W linker  : /data/data/org.test.weather/files/libpymodules.so: is missing DT_SONAME will use basename as a replacement: "libpymodules.so"
04-07 09:56:39.311 12803 12822 W linker  : /data/data/org.test.weather/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.so: is missing DT_SONAME will use basename as a replacement: "_ctypes.so"
04-07 09:56:39.340 12803 12822 I python  : [INFO              ] [Factory     ] 179 symbols loaded
04-07 09:56:39.776 12803 12822 I python  :  /data/user/0/org.test.weather/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/core/image/img_pygame.py:13: RuntimeWarning: import cdrom: No module named cdrom
04-07 09:56:39.777 12803 12822 I python  :  (ImportError: No module named cdrom)
04-07 09:56:39.801 12803 12822 I python  : [INFO              ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif, img_pygame (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
04-07 09:56:39.842 12803 12822 I python  : [INFO              ] [Text        ] Provider: pygame
04-07 09:56:39.922 12803 12822 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
04-07 09:56:39.922 12803 12822 I python  :    File "/home/arnau/Projectes/Kivy/oreilly/arnau/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 173, in <module>
04-07 09:56:39.923 12803 12822 I python  :    File "/home/arnau/Projectes/Kivy/oreilly/arnau/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/app.py", line 801, in run
04-07 09:56:39.923 12803 12822 I python  :    File "/home/arnau/Projectes/Kivy/oreilly/arnau/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/app.py", line 598, in load_kv
04-07 09:56:39.923 12803 12822 I python  :    File "/home/arnau/Projectes/Kivy/oreilly/arnau/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1842, in load_file
04-07 09:56:39.924 12803 12822 I python  :    File "/home/arnau/Projectes/Kivy/oreilly/arnau/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1889, in load_string
04-07 09:56:39.924 12803 12822 I python  :    File "/home/arnau/Projectes/Kivy/oreilly/arnau/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1264, in __init__
04-07 09:56:39.925 12803 12822 I python  :    File "/home/arnau/Projectes/Kivy/oreilly/arnau/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1363, in parse
04-07 09:56:39.925 12803 12822 I python  :    File "/home/arnau/Projectes/Kivy/oreilly/arnau/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1329, in execute_directives
04-07 09:56:39.925 12803 12822 I python  :  ValueError: Empty module name
04-07 09:56:39.959 12803 12822 I python  : Python for android ended.
04-07 09:56:39.967 12803 12822 I art     : System.exit called, status: 0
04-07 09:56:39.967 12803 12822 I AndroidRuntime: VM exiting with result code 0, cleanup skipped.
04-07 09:56:39.987  4817 10578 D GraphicsStats: Buffer count: 8
04-07 09:56:39.987  4817 10581 I WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{8a7984e u0 org.test.weather/org.renpy.android.PythonActivity}
04-07 09:56:39.988  4817 10581 W WindowManager: Force-removing child win Window{6ff9d14 u0 SurfaceView - org.test.weather/org.renpy.android.PythonActivity} from container Window{8a7984e u0 org.test.weather/org.renpy.android.PythonActivity}
04-07 09:56:39.988  4817 11069 I ActivityManager: Process org.test.weather:python (pid 12803) has died
04-07 09:56:39.988  4817 11069 D ActivityManager: cleanUpApplicationRecord -- 12803
04-07 09:56:39.988  4817 11069 W ActivityManager: Force removing ActivityRecord{2bb1b23 u0 org.test.weather/org.renpy.android.PythonActivity t5730}: app died, no saved state
04-07 09:56:39.996  4817 14653 W WindowManager: Failed looking up window
04-07 09:56:39.996  4817 14653 W WindowManager: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window android.os.BinderProxy@a17cd6f does not exist
04-07 09:56:39.996  4817 14653 W WindowManager:     at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:9415)
04-07 09:56:39.996  4817 14653 W WindowManager:     at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:9406)
04-07 09:56:39.996  4817 14653 W WindowManager:     at com.android.server.wm.WindowState$DeathRecipient.binderDied(WindowState.java:1800)
04-07 09:56:39.996  4817 14653 W WindowManager:     at android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice(Binder.java:688)
04-07 09:56:39.996  4817 14653 I WindowManager: WIN DEATH: null
04-07 09:56:40.062  7424  7522 I Adreno  : QUALCOMM build                   : a5b4970, If5818605d9
04-07 09:56:40.062  7424  7522 I Adreno  : Build Date                       : 10/12/16
04-07 09:56:40.062  7424  7522 I Adreno  : OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.09.00.04
04-07 09:56:40.062  7424  7522 I Adreno  : Local Branch                     : N24D
04-07 09:56:40.062  7424  7522 I Adreno  : Remote Branch                    : 
04-07 09:56:40.062  7424  7522 I Adreno  : Remote Branch                    : 
04-07 09:56:40.062  7424  7522 I Adreno  : Reconstruct Branch               : 
04-07 09:56:40.099  7424  7522 I OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
04-07 09:56:40.099  7424  7522 D OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
04-07 09:56:44.430  7299 11444 I PlaceInferenceEngine: [anon] Setup for configuration 105:[]
04-07 09:56:44.430  7299 11444 I PlaceInferenceEngine: [anon] Active modules after start(): 0
04-07 09:56:49.297 14637 14637 I MemoryTrimmer: Trimming objects from memory, since app is in the background.
04-07 09:56:49.369 14637 14637 I MemoryTrimmer: Trimming objects from memory, since app is in the background.
```

Comment: Thanks for your time